# Shoud I resize image for mask RCNN?

Tags: image, computer-vision

I am training custom object detection by using mask RCNN. I have custom images that are of different sizes, so I am wondering if I need to resize the images so that they are all of the same size or not?

And if so, which method should I use to resize them?

Also I guess that I have to resize before labeling the images right?

Comment: can you add more information about which package, language you are using ? 
i presume its tensorflow and python ?

Comment: Yes I am using tensorflow and python and I would like to know if all the images need to be of the same size when you annotate them and feed them in?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to resize it before hand.

you can use this option in the model config file to set the size limit for your training.

```
 image_resizer {
  keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
    min_dimension: 600
    max_dimension: 1024
  }
}
```

Please make sure all the bounding boxes are in range with the image dimensions. i.e. the within the range of width and height of the image. Then the boxes and the images will be auto resized according to the parameter set here.

Answer (score 0):

In Matterplot's Mask RCNN you can find documentation in the config file:

```py
# Input image resizing
# Generally, use the "square" resizing mode for training and predicting
# and it should work well in most cases. In this mode, images are scaled
# up such that the small side is = IMAGE_MIN_DIM, but ensuring that the
# scaling doesn't make the long side > IMAGE_MAX_DIM. Then the image is
# padded with zeros to make it a square so multiple images can be put
# in one batch.
# Available resizing modes:
# none:   No resizing or padding. Return the image unchanged.
# square: Resize and pad with zeros to get a square image
#         of size [max_dim, max_dim].
# pad64:  Pads width and height with zeros to make them multiples of 64.
#         If IMAGE_MIN_DIM or IMAGE_MIN_SCALE are not None, then it scales
#         up before padding. IMAGE_MAX_DIM is ignored in this mode.
#         The multiple of 64 is needed to ensure smooth scaling of feature
#         maps up and down the 6 levels of the FPN pyramid (2**6=64).
# crop:   Picks random crops from the image. First, scales the image based
#         on IMAGE_MIN_DIM and IMAGE_MIN_SCALE, then picks a random crop of
#         size IMAGE_MIN_DIM x IMAGE_MIN_DIM. Can be used in training only.
#         IMAGE_MAX_DIM is not used in this mode.
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE = "square"
IMAGE_MIN_DIM = 800
IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 1024
```

How I understand it. When you train or predict this configuration will be used without you having to resize it manually. Ofcourse if you have different sizes and ratios of images this can be a problem.

- 512x512: ratio = 1 so this will upscale to 1024x1024
- 2054x2456: ratio = 0.836... so this will downscale to 1024x1024 keeping the ratio of 0.836... but **using zeropadding** to get the square shape.

Where it could go wrong is if a dimension of an object is relatively smaller or bigger in comparison with the different image dimensions which can result in a stretched or compressed object. In this case you should preprocess it manually so that in the end your object is of the same size and shape after the Mask RCNN function has molded it into the right shape.

The Matterplot function is found in "utils.py" and is called "resize_image".
In the "model.py" this is used during training when loading in the data and during inference (detect) to reshape the given numpy-array.